# can not load code from adruino ide to eso8266

Tags: arduino-esp8266

I designed a esp8266 board. I use ch340 driver.  When i load code from arduino ide to esp8266 boar, I have encountered this error and cannot load the code
this is error

```
Sketch uses 257096 bytes (24%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 26540 bytes (32%) of dynamic memory, leaving 55380 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
esptool.py v2.6
2.6
esptool.py v2.6
Serial port COM8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2/tools/upload.py", line 25, in <module>
    esptool.main(fakeargs)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2652, in main
    esp = chip_class(each_port, initial_baud, args.trace)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 222, in __init__
    self._port = serial.serial_for_url(port)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/pyserial\serial\__init__.py", line 88, in serial_for_url
    instance.open()
  File "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/pyserial\serial\serialwin32.py", line 78, in open
    self._reconfigure_port()
  File "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/pyserial\serial\serialwin32.py", line 222, in _reconfigure_port
    'Original message: {!r}'.format(ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)
```

Answer (score 0):

Great, but the issue is withe the device as it cannot communicate with it.
Reason driver issue firstly make sure that you cane see the ch340 in you computer management after connecting it.
Then try uploading it.
If you are unable to see it then probably the issue is with the driver you have installed.